# how i can show an image with a hyperlink?

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink

when I try to show an image with a hyperlink, I got this error "#NOM?" ...how can I handle this problem ?, please help me

```
// The function below will give me all the images as an object
let test = getAssets("images test");

  let txt =[];
  for (x in test) 
      {
       txt.push(test[x]);
      };

  for(let i =0;i<results.length;i++)
  {
    
    sheet_show.getRange(7,7).setFormula(`=LIEN_HYPERTEXTE("${txt[0]}";"${results[i][0].toString()}")`);
    sheet_show.getRange(7,6).setValue(results[i][1]);
    sheet_show.getRange(7,5).setValue(results[i][2]);

  }
```

Comment: Can you try providing the missing details? `getAssets` function and `results` source value are some of them. A lot of details that should be shown are not available. If you could provide the whole code while pointing out the issue, would be better.

Answer (score 1):

#### Error:

[image: error]

#### Issue:

`#NOM` is `#NAME` in english right? If that's it, then I believe the formula is typed incorrectly or the parameter is not recognized.

> The #NAME? formula parse error signifies a problem with your formula syntax.
> The most common reason for this error is a misspelling in one of your function names.

> Another reason for a #NAME? error is referencing a named range which doesn’t actually exist, or is misspelt.

But based on your problem, it might have been the former.

- I am not sure if the error was caused because `LIEN_HYPERTEXTE` is actually not a proper formula or just a locale issue, but try replacing `LIEN_HYPERTEXTE` to `HYPERLINK`. I do have some assumptions below but in total, that would work.

#### Code:

```
function addHyperlink() {
  let test = getAssets("images test");
  let txt = [];
  for (x in test) {
    txt.push(test[x]);
  }

  var sheet_show = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Assuming results would look like this.
  var results = [
    ['image1', 'image1 description 1', 'image1 description 2'], 
    ['image2', 'image2 description 1', 'image2 description 2']
  ];

  for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    // Used a simpler way of appending string to the variables
    // Added an i on getRange row so multiple images won't overwrite each other
    // Used i on txt variable as well
    sheet_show.getRange(7 + i, 7).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + txt[i] + '";"' + results[i][0].toString() + '")');
    sheet_show.getRange(7 + i, 6).setValue(results[i][1]);
    sheet_show.getRange(7 + i, 5).setValue(results[i][2]);
  }
}

// Assuming your getAssets would return the links of the files found on the parameter
function getAssets(driveDir) {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveDir);
  var folder = (folders.hasNext())? folders.next() : false ;
  var assets = {};
  if(folder){
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var fileName = file.getName();
      assets[fileName] = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=' + file.getId();
    }
  }
  return assets;
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Resources:

- [#NAME](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/formula-parse-error/#errorName)